# Updating blank cells to NULL causes ALL cells to be NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a query that I'm trying to use to update only cells with empty strings to NULL. But instead, when I run this command ALL of the cells end up being NULL:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET InvoiceId=NULL,
 LinkedAccountId=NULL,
 RecordId=NULL,
 ProductName=NULL,
 RateId=NULL,
 SubscriptionId=NULL,
 PricingPlanId=NULL,
 UsageType=NULL,
 Operation=NULL,
 AvailabilityZone=NULL,
 ReservedInstance=NULL,
 UsageStartDate=NULL,
 UsageEndDate=NULL,
 UsageQuantity=NULL,
 BlendedRate=NULL,
 UnBlendedRate=NULL,
 ResourceId=NULL,
 Engagement=NULL,
 Name=NULL,
 Owner=NULL,
 Parent=NULL 
WHERE InvoiceId='' 
 OR LinkedAccountId='' 
 OR RecordId='' 
 OR ProductName='' 
 OR RateId='' 
 OR SubscriptionId='' 
 OR PricingPlanId='' 
 OR UsageType='' 
 OR UsageEndDate='' 
 OR Operation='' 
 OR AvailabilityZone='' 
 OR ReservedInstance='' 
 OR UsageStartDate='' 
 OR UsageEndDate='' 
 OR UsageQuantity='' 
 OR BlendedRate='' 
 OR UnBlendedRate='' 
 OR ResourceId='' 
 OR Engagement='' 
 OR Name=''
 OR Owner='' 
 OR Parent='';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're assuming that the terms in your WHERE clause have an implicit correlation with the assignments in your SET clause, so only some columns will be set, depending on which ones satisfy individual terms in the WHERE clause. This is not how SQL works.

What really happens is that the *whole* condition of the WHERE clause is evaluated to select which *rows* are affected. Then *all* the SET assignments are applied, so all columns will be changed on the rows that satisfy the whole WHERE clause condition.

To do what you want in one pass, you could do it this way:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET InvoiceId=NULLIF(InvoiceId, ''),
 LinkedAccountId=NULLIF(LinkedAccountId, ''),
 RecordId=NULLIF(RecordId, ''),
 ProductName=NULLIF(ProductName, ''),
 RateId=NULLIF(RateId, ''),
 SubscriptionId=NULLIF(SubscriptionId, ''),
 PricingPlanId=NULLIF(PricingPlanId, ''),
 UsageType=NULLIF(UsageTYpe, ''),
 Operation=NULLIF(Operation, ''),
 AvailabilityZone=NULLIF(AvailabilityZone, ''),
 ReservedInstance=NULLIF(ReservedInstance, ''),
 UsageStartDate=NULLIF(UsageStartDate, ''),
 UsageEndDate=NULLIF(UsageEndDate, ''),
 UsageQuantity=NULLIF(UsageQuantity, ''),
 BlendedRate=NULLIF(BlendedRate, ''),
 UnBlendedRate=NULLIF(UnBlendedRate, ''),
 ResourceId=NULLIF(ResourceId, ''),
 Engagement=NULLIF(Engagement, ''),
 Name=NULLIF(Name, ''),
 Owner=NULLIF(Owner, ''),
 Parent=NULLIF(Parent, '')
```

The [NULLIF() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) returns NULL if its two arguments are equal, otherwise it returns the first argument. So in the case that each column is *not* `''` then it is a no-op, setting the column to its own original value.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting ALL fields to `NULL` where any field = `''`

You might need to write as many queries as fields you want to update.

I might be wrong, but I don't think this is possible to do in a single query

```
UPDATE table_name
SET InvoiceId = NULL
WHERE InvoiceId = ''
```

And this for every fields

Answer (score 2):

The way to interpret your SQL query is kind of like this:

```
UPDATE table_name

SET
  (all these fields to null)
WHERE
 (if ANY Of these conditions is true)
```

I agree with Cid that it might be the safest to do 1 field per query at a time, but this is how you could write this in a single query:

```
UPDATE table_name SET
  field1 = IF(field1='',NULL,field1),
  field2 = IF(field2='',NULL,field2),
  /* etc */
```